# Converting an arbitrary JSON string to Kafka Schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka Connect successfully but I have a JSON string that I am trying to convert in a common/consistent fashion to a Kafka Schema.  Is there a way to convert an arbitrary JSON string into a "SourceRecord" that can be consumed by Kafka Connect.  I suspect there is a simple way to do this but so far I have not been able to find a good/working example that does what I am looking for.

Right now I can successfully convert the JSON string on a case-by-case basis as per the example as follows.  The example shown is trivial, but I am hoping there a way to do this for any arbitrarily complex JSON string and create the Schema output (key and value) required by SourceRecord?

(Note: this is done in a Kafka Connect plugin "poll()" method)

```
:
:
long l = generateId();
Long id = Long.valueOf(l);
Object key = buildKey(id);
Schema keySchema = HttpSourceSchemas.KEY_SCHEMA;
Object value = buildValue(timestampStr, "hello world");
Schema valueSchema = HttpSourceSchemas.VALUE_SCHEMA;

records.add(new SourceRecord(
                    sourcePartition, sourceOffset, topic, partition,
                    keySchema, key, valueSchema, value));
:
:
private Struct buildKey(Long id) {
    return new Struct(HttpSourceSchemas.KEY_SCHEMA)
                .put(HttpSourceSchemas.ID_FIELD, id);
}

private Struct buildValue(String timestamp, String data) {
    return new Struct(HttpSourceSchemas.VALUE_SCHEMA)
                .put(HttpSourceSchemas.TIMESTAMP_FIELD, timestamp)
                .put(HttpSourceSchemas.DATA_FIELD, data);
}
:
:
```

My schema look like this:

```
public final class HttpSourceSchemas {

    private HttpSourceSchemas() {
        // Empty
    }

    public static final String ID_FIELD = "id";
    public static final String TIMESTAMP_FIELD = "timestamp";
    public static final String DATA_FIELD = "data";

    public static final Schema KEY_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct()
        .name("Key Schema")
        .version(1)
        .field(ID_FIELD, Schema.INT64_SCHEMA)
        .build();

    public static final Schema VALUE_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct()
        .name("Value Schema")
        .version(1)
        .field(TIMESTAMP_FIELD, Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
        .field(DATA_FIELD, Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Ideally, you should not use a specific serialization format within the Connect API. This is the purpose of Converter classes on the outside of the connector task code. Stick to Struct/Schema objects (after parsing data that comes from other places... Kafka comes with Jackson, though, so use that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pick a JSON-processing library such as [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (recommended, as this is included by `connect-api` dependency) or [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)
2. Parse the arbitrary string and get a JSON object in Java.
3. Do a depth-first-search to traverse through the nodes of the JSON object.
4. Build its Kafka schema.

Some code in Kafka's [JsonConverter](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/da58d75c4389aa988ac6028bb8bd073646f07300/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java#L561) should help you.